# "NumberFormatException For input string" HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to run a HIVE SQL similar to below code

```
insert into table FactUpdated
  select colm_name  
  from  
  (
  select colmn_name, floor(rand()*116219) rand_key 
  from FactTable limit 2942699191) line
  join  DimTable
  on FactTable.rand_key = DimTable.id;
```

while running this query i am getting **FAILED: NumberFormatException For input string: "2942699191"**

I seems like limit clause in hive has some limitation in terms of value it can take.

Can someone help me with this query.

PS: Hive Version 1.2.1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`limit` should be an integer.

**2^31 - 1** works

```
select  1
limit   2147483647
;
```

**2^31** is out of range and returns the same error you get

```
select  1
limit   2147483648
;
```

---

[LimitOperator.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/LimitOperator.java)

```
public class LimitOperator extends Operator<LimitDesc> implements Serializable {   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected transient int limit;      ...
```

Comment: yes that is working fine, is there any way to change the datatype of limit or use any overloaded class?

Comment: Limit is defined as `int` in the source code (see updated answer). In any case your request does not seem to make much sense. What is your motivation here?

Comment: i need to have a table with 10B records and in that i have to generate 7B records from script and rest need to be copied back from same table in this case i need to copy 2.94B. which is what i am trying to achive.

Comment: have a table with 10B record = (7B from script + 3B (copied from 7B generated earlier)) - this is kind of Duplicacy of 3B records

Comment: So you are trying to retrieve specific 3B records out of 10B records? What makes you think that the limit will return you those records and not part of the 7B records or a mix of both of them?

Comment: P.s. if the data was generated by different process then it split between different files. You just have to find the relevant files.